# How to pluralize ellipsis?

Tags: code-golf, string

It's obviously ellipsisessieses.

Inspired by [a chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39560898#39560898).

## Your challenge

Given a list or space or comma-separated string of words, ellipsisessiesesify them.

To ellipsisessieses-ify a word:

1. Start with the word.
2. Add the first letter of the original word to the end.
3. Add 2 of the last letter of the original word to the end.
4. Add the second-to-last letter of the original word to the end.
5. Add the first letter of the original word to the end.
6. Add the last letter of the original word to the end.
7. Repeat steps 5 & 6 once.
8. You're done!

## You can assume:

- The input words will only be alphanumeric
- Input & output can be a space-separated string or list
- The input will contain only words
- The words will be at least 2 letters long
- The input will match the regex `/^[a-z0-9]{2,}( [a-z0-9]{2,})*$/i`
- You can have a different input and output format
- *More to come...*

## Test cases:

```
ellipsis -> ellipsisessieses
goat -> goatgttagtgt
covfefe -> covfefeceefcece
programmer5000 -> programmer5000p000p0p0
up vote down goat -> upuppuupup voteveetveve downdnnwdndn goatgttagtgt
it is golf yo -> itittiitit isissiisis golfgfflgfgf yoyooyyoyo
crossed out 44 is still 44 -> crossedcddecdcd outottuotot 4444444444 isissiisis stillslllslsl 4444444444
```

Shorteststtsstst answerarrearar ininniinin bytesbssebsbs winswssnwsws!

Comment: Pretty sure the "e"s in "ellipsisessieses" is from "ellipses" (except the first "e")

Comment: I *still* don't know how to pluralize ellipsis... **EDIT**: apparently, it's ellipses.

Comment: For step 2, I think it should just be add an e, not add the first letter

Comment: It's *ellipses*. Other plurals that have the same spelling but different pronunciation for a word ending in -is and a word ending in -e are *axes* and *bases*.

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>58</s> 57 bytes

*NB: This turns out to use the same trick as Jonathan Allan in [this Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140393/58563) (though I noticed after posting).*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Jonathan Allan*

Works on arrays of strings.

```js
s=>s.map(s=>s+'01120101'.replace(/./g,n=>s.substr(-n,1)))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>s.map(s=>s+'01120101'.replace(/./g,n=>s.substr(-n,1)))

console.log(f(['ellipsis']))
console.log(f(['goat']))
console.log(f(['covfefe']))
console.log(f(['programmer5000']))
console.log(f(['up', 'vote', 'down', 'goat']))
console.log(f(['it', 'is', 'golf', 'yo']))
console.log(f(['crossed', 'out', '44', 'is', 'still', '44']))
```

Comment: Woah, this is cool! Nice job!

Comment: I believe you can save a byte by replacing `21102121` with `01120101` and `n-2` with `-n`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13 12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁽×ʠb3’ịṭµ€K
```

A full program that takes a list of lists of characters and prints the space separated output.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R497D008tSDJ@1DDz4e7uhzvXHtr6qGmN9////6OVSguUdBSUyvJLUkF0Sn55HohOz08sUYoFAA)**

#### How?

```
⁽×ʠb3’ịṭµ€K - Main link: list of lists of characters e.g. ["this","is","it"]
        µ€  - for each word in the input:            e.g. "this"
⁽×ʠ         -   base 250 literal 5416                     5416
   b3       -   converted to base 3                       [2,1,1,0,2,1,2,1]
     ’      -   decrement                                 [1,0,0,-1,1,0,1,0]
      ị     -   index into the word                       "tssitsts"
       ṭ    -   tack to the word                          ["this",["tssitsts"]]
          K - join the results with spaces                ["this",["tssitsts"]," is",["issiisis"]," it",["ittiitit"]]
            - implicit print                              thistssitsts isissiisis itittiitit
```

---

Alternatively a list of words to list of words is also possible in **11 bytes**:

```
⁽×ʠb3’ị;@µ€
```

`⁽×ʠb3’` may also be replaced by `4,⁵Bj-` for the same byte count
(`[4,10]` in binary is `[[1,0,0],[1,0,1,0]]` joined by `-1` is `[1,0,0,-1,1,0,1,0]`).

Comment: Do you need to join the results with spaces? You are allowed to output a list / a list of lists.

Comment: @programmer5000 Yeah, joining with spaces is optional here

Comment: @programmer5000 There is an alternative 11 byter that returns a list which I have given below the main answer (note that there is no way to get the main one down to 10 by removing the `K` because as a monadic link the returned list would not be one level deep, which I imagine is pushing lax I/O too far - that is for an input of `["this", "is", "it"]` the return value would be `[['t','h','i','s',"tssitsts"],['i','s',"issiisis"],['i','t',"ittiitit"]]` (where "..." are lists of characters) and leaving it to print as a full program would smash it all together as `thistssitstsisissiisisitittiitit`)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
εD•Lz•3вÍèJ«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3FaXRw2LfKqAhPGFTYd7D6/wOrT6//9o9cwSdR31zGIgkZ6fkwakKvPVYwE)

**Explanation**

```
ε              # apply on each word in input
 D             # duplicate the word
  •Lz•         # push the base-255 compressed number 5416
      3в       # convert to a list of base-3 digits (yields [2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1])
        Í      # subtract 2 from each (yields [0, -1, -1, -2, 0, -1, 0, -1])
         è     # index into the word with these numbers
          J    # join to string
           «   # append to the original word
```

Comment: Hehe, great minds...

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Yeah, we had exactly the same idea it seems. Jellys shorter compression won the day this time :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>52</s> 49 bytes

3 bytes thanks to Arnauld.

```
(\w)(\w+)
$1$2$1
(.)(.)(.)\b
$1$2$3$2$2$1$3$2$3$2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrBCoMwEETv@xV7yMFQKNrav/ESdSML0Q3ZqPTr01RhHjPMTKLMmyulGU5beVgwnXmZDpqnvTWMd/Wu1OHySikUAkdlhUVchkkOT54gJlmSW1dKn7ZtYY94SCac5dzwOnJG1hqDx6/AlESVZpQ9Y9//F80cQs0/)

Comment: That third line of code reminds me of a mutant from Total Recall.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Who was inspired by Eccentrica Gallumbits mentioned in the Hitch-Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 56 bytes

```python
lambda s:[i+i[0]+i[-1]*2+i[-2]+(i[0]+i[-1])*2for i in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BDoIwEETvfMXeioIJEr2Q8CW1B5QWNyls0y0Yvx4pENnDzs7LZjLuG940lLOpH7Nt@mfbAFcSM5SFWtblqs5l1FJl6cFO59KQBwQcgNUcNAeGGqQU2lp0jCxUDlJ01ITtetFktNGbcZ463/S99veiKDY2OpGDmCjoqC19hqhHAIbol@CVWhP1S3u4J2bdRkTj@ne7Hd8c0NodKpUk/@Zr7SqBZZzHIYBJ8TT/AA)

I think this is my fastest FGITW and it's not even that impressive. :P

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

```python
lambda k:[x+''.join(x[-int(i)]for i in"01120101")for x in k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NDoIwEITvPMXGSyX@pPhzMfFJag8ora6UbtNWhKdHChr3MjtfNpMd18cH2f2gz5fBlM21KqE@iW7F2PZJaJed2KCNS8ylJg8IaBe8KHa84MUiT6gbEdRyiCrEAGcQgilj0AUMTK5BsDuVcd5u1Gql1Wycp7svm0b5I@d8Zi/H1sBaiippRW@b9B@AMfkxeKJGJ@3pG@4pBFUlRK/p7nD4X4eIxnyhlFn2KwPT26cMxnE@NdVj13z4AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ «ι↑Ｅ”o∨↙8”§ι±Ｉκ→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYuxCsIwFEVn@xWPTC@QQuNYJ3HqUBGLHxDamAZDEtrXKIjfHuPgnc45cMdZLWNQLud7WACH6Cxh5@NGAy3WG@QCGDDO4V3tLqUQWn74Y3uLAnoVkTVS7hvZSCbgSJ2f9AutgLM2ijSe1Er44L@Vax@SxvZqzUxFPzlvEVIgDVN4ejBBUZXrlOvVfQE) Link is to verbose version of code. Only happened to read @Arnauld's answer after coding this but this is basically a port of it. Explanation:

```
Ｆ   «                   Loop over
  Ｓ                     Input string
 ⪪                       Split at spaces
     ι                  Print the word
        ”o∨↙8”          Compressed string 01120101
       Ｅ                Map over each character
                 Ｉκ     Cast character to integer
                ±       Negate
              §ι        Circularly index into word
      ↑                 Print array upwards, prints each element rightwards
                    →    Move right
```

Comment: [18 bytes maybe?](https://tio.run/##NYuxCsIwFABn/YpHpxdoIXGskzh1qIjiB4Q2pMGShOY1FcRvf8bBm@6GGya9DEHPzNvkZgPY@bjSnRbnLQoB7/3uWpzQieNf20esodcRK6nUQSqpqhpO1PnRvNDVcDFWk8GzToRP8aOsfcgG25uzE5X8MK8RciADY9g82KCJm8xNmrlZ0hc)

Comment: @ASCII-only Wouldn't you have to add extra bytes for the `-rs` flag?

Comment: Not sure, I guess so? `-rs` is there just to disable printing the input prompt though

Comment: Should I just make `-rs` mode the default instead?

Answer (score 3):

## sed, 46 bytes

```
s/^\(\(.\).*\(.\)\(.\)\)$/\1\2\4\4\3\2\4\2\4/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/LkYjRkMvRlNPC0xBCE0V/RjDGKMYEyA0BtNArJ/@/39qTk5mQXFmMQA)

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, <s>51</s> 49 bytes

Requires `⎕ML←3`

```
∊{⍺,' ',⍵}/{S←1,L←≢⍵⋄⍵,⍵[∊S(L-0 1)S S]}¨' '(≠⊂⊢)⍞
```

-9 bytes thanks to @Adám in chat!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcYgFpB@1NFV/ah3l466grrOo96ttfrVwUBRQx2Qmkedi4BCj7pbgCRIMhqoOFjDR9dAwVAzWCE4tvbQCqA2jUedCx51NT3qWqT5qHfe//@lBQpl@SWpCin55XkK6fmJJQA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>74</s> 60 bytes

```
s=>s.map(s=>s+(a=s[l=s.length-1],b=s[0])+a+a+s[l-1]+b+a+b+a)
```

Takes input as an array, and outputs an array.

-9 bytes thanks to Programmer5000

**Test cases:**

```js
let f=

s=>s.map(s=>s+(a=s[l=s.length-1],b=s[0])+a+a+s[l-1]+b+a+b+a)

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['ellipsis']))) // ellipsisessieses
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['goat']))) // goatgttagtgt
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['covfefe']))) // covfefeceefcece
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['programmer5000']))) // programmer5000p000p0p0
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['up', 'vote', 'down', 'goat']))) // upuppuupup,voteveetveve,downdnnwdndn,goatgttagtgt
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['it', 'is', 'golf', 'yo']))) // itittiitit,isissiisis,golfgfflgfgf,yoyooyyoyo
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(['crossed', 'out', '44', 'is', 'still', '44']))) // crossedcddecdcd,outottuotot,4444444444,isissiisis,stillslllslsl,4444444444
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 89 bytes

```
((f[a_]:=#~StringTake~a;k=#<>(q=f@1)<>(w=f[-1])<>w<>f@{-2}<>q<>w<>q<>w)&/@StringSplit@#)&
```

Comment: There's no mathematica `Ellipsisessieses` builtin? :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

Uses the same trick as in [@Jonathan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140393/59487).

```
m+dsm@dttkj5416 3
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2Bdsm%40dttkj5416+3&input=%5B%27ellipsis%27%5D&test_suite_input=%5B%27ellipsis%27%5D%0A%5B%27goat%27%5D%0A%5B%27covfefe%27%5D%0A%5B%27programmer5000%27%5D%0A%5B%27up%27%2C+%27vote%27%2C+%27down%27%2C+%27goat%27%5D%0A%5B%27it%27%2C+%27is%27%2C+%27golf%27%2C+%27yo%27%5D%0A%5B%27crossed%27%2C+%27out%27%2C+%2744%27%2C+%27is%27%2C+%27still%27%2C+%2744%27%5D&debug=0)** or [**Check out the test Suite** (Give it some time).](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2Bdsm%40dttkj5416+3&input=%5B%27ellipsis%27%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%27ellipsis%27%5D%0A%5B%27goat%27%5D%0A%5B%27covfefe%27%5D%0A%5B%27programmer5000%27%5D%0A%5B%27up%27%2C+%27vote%27%2C+%27down%27%2C+%27goat%27%5D%0A%5B%27it%27%2C+%27is%27%2C+%27golf%27%2C+%27yo%27%5D%0A%5B%27crossed%27%2C+%27out%27%2C+%2744%27%2C+%27is%27%2C+%27still%27%2C+%2744%27%5D&debug=0)

Port of my Python solution, <s>**19 bytes**</s> **18 bytes**:

```
m+dsm@d_k+0j1144 3
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Paradoc](https://github.com/betaveros/paradoc) (v0.2.10), 13? bytes (CP-1252)

```
µ96Qó3BÌDX=v+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsSkzJT/6vVFqgUJZfkqqQkl@ep5Cen1iiFP7/0FZLs8DDm42dDve4RNiWaf@vTfgPAA)

Takes a list of words, and results in a list of words on the stack.

A small variation on the base-3 trick. Maybe it's time to work on my base 250-whatever compressor.

Explanation:

```
μ             .. Map the following block over each word (the block is
              .. terminated by }, but that doesn't exist, so until EOF)
              .. (The word is on the stack now.)
 96Qó         .. 96 * 26 (Q in base 26) = 2496, a hack to prevent us from
              .. needing a space to separate this from the following number.
     3B       .. Convert 2496 to base 3 to get [1,0,1,0,2,1,1,0]
       ÌD     .. Negate and reverse to get [0,-1,-1,-2,0,-1,0,-1]
         X    .. Push the loop variable: the word being mapped over
          =v  .. Index, vectorize; map over the indices by indexing them
              .. into the word
            + .. Concatenate with the original word
```

(Byte-counting question: Now that I'm actually demonstrating this in TIO, it take a list of words on the stack and results in a list of words on the stack, but you can't really do much with that list of words unless you close the block started by µ. Should I count that closing brace?)

Comment: *Should I cound that closing brace?* Yes, if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

## Wolfram Language/Mathematica, 66 bytes

```
StringJoin[StringSplit[#,""]/.{a_,___,b_,c_}:>{#,a,c,c,b,a,c,a,c}]&
```

Just whipped it up real quick, might have a minor improvement here or there.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>38</s> 30 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to ASCII-only.*

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ «ι§ι⁰×²§ι±¹§ι±²×²⁺§ι⁰§ι±¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BCsIwEETv@Yqlp11sQXvtyWMPitAvCG2sgZCEuqmK@O1rBQ/NoXPbneEN09/01AftRK5hAuyis4ytj4k7nqwfkUoooCCCt4JFl@XJaKlZXUdu/WCeaEvYU@ackmMb3QvrElapsxk1GzwQ0RboH6lpG7jLizcbMsBvS6M@IinCHNjAEB4exqBZSTVLdXdf) Link is to verbose version.

Note the trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>55</s> 49 + 1 (-a) = <s>56</s> 50 bytes

*used a trick from @Arrnauld's post to save a couple bytes*

```perl
say map$_.'01120101 '=~s/\d/substr$_,-$&,1/egr,@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhN7FAJV5P3cDQ0MjA0MBQQd22rlg/JkW/uDSpuKRIJV5HV0VNx1A/Nb1Ix8Ht///0/MQShcySf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9YD6/usmAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 117 bytes

```java
a->{int i=0,l;for(String s:a){char c=s.charAt(0),d=s.charAt(l=s.length()-1);a[i++]+=""+c+d+d+s.charAt(l-1)+c+d+c+d;}}
```

Takes the input as a String-array, and modified this original array instead of returning a new one to save bytes.

Can most likely be golfed some more..

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##tVPLboMwELznK1acQCSISumlFpXyAc0lxygH1xjq1NjIXogixLfT5dHk0mMRmPUOs55ZG6685TtbS3PNvwdV1dYhXAlLGlQ6OTjH755thObewwdXptsAKIPSFVxIOI4pQGtVDiI8oVOmPF94xAjuadDtkaMScAQDGQx8995ROags3WpWWLcUgX/jUSe@uAOR@WScHDBMo23@zDRNtTQlfoXR7iVi/Kzi@BJnQRCLOKfryaTXE0aD9f3AZit186nJyuJoMl1RSw/fQBamfp7A2D/5NvL2ALtAaq1qr3zQs4luEhFOzGjOT3ePskpsg0lNNahNOG9kgnZeZaEv/L9VSstxXQVh20IWcl2R2tnS8aqS7jVN03W1mjrYBq1FSSG3N0Nh/V1USDL0MYxauqBwtysfm7Pey5yUaCF67ve/Bjz9s3pG/sVBv@mHHw)

```java
a->{                          // Method with String-array as parameter and no return-type
  int i=0,                    //  Index-integer (starting at 0)
      l;                      //  Length-integer which we use multiple times
  for(String s:a){            //  Loop over the input array
    char c=s.charAt(0),       //   The first character of the word
         d=s.charAt(          //   The last character of the word
            l=s.length()-1);  //    and set `l` at the same time to `length()-1`
    a[i++]+=                  //   Append to the current value in the array:
      ""                      //    String so the characters aren't appended as integers
      +c                      //    + the first character
      +d+d                    //    + two times the last character
      +s.charAt(l-1)          //    + the single-last character
      +c+d+c+d;               //    + the first + last character two times
  }                           //  End of loop
}                             // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 106 bytes

```cs
n=>{for(int i=0,x;i<n.Length;){var h=n[i];x=h.Length-1;char y=h[0],j=h[x];n[i++]=h+y+j+j+h[x-1]+y+j+y+j;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU7BboMwDL3nKyxOIErVntNUqnbtDtMOO6AcoswQF@ZMJGMgxLezMG2yrSc/@z09GyrrB9y@AnELr3OI@CGF7U0I8LKIEE0kC6Ond3g2xHmxiJuN5PkS4pAktb62amN1XRo/5MQRSJ0Ok6QLH@/IbXSyWEYzgFNck5aTcn98dZbWpcOsXH3Sh0eCScv0VJZauXIuH6kSV53175JGrusmBUDq3bJTjN/wn2PJsO/pM1DIDlnrTUxg/dhgg9m6q9q8K6RIMdFYl@8GIxBDVzx5Dr7H49tAEe/EmI/FLljFuv0A)

Lambda function that takes input as array of strings, and modifies original array for output